# How can I get jQuery DatePicker to not break a <span> or <input> element when called?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, datepicker

Something in the HTML or in the way I am using jQuery Datepicker breaks the targeted  element `editable-post-name-full` in this HTML. This HTML is generated by WordPress; I can't build a fiddle to emulate it.

This is the HTML; the span I'm trying to target is called #editable-post-name before the "Edit" button is clicked.

```
<span id="sample-permalink">
<a href="https://www.example.com/?p=1000" target='wp-preview-2198'>https://www.example.com/<span id="editable-post-name">test-post</span>/</a>
</span>

<span id="edit-slug-buttons">
<button type="button" class="edit-slug button button-small hide-if-no-js" aria-label="Edit permalink">Edit</button>
</span>
<span id="editable-post-name-full">test-post</span>
```

After the Edit button is clicked, the span tag is broken and shows `" autocomplete="off" />/` in the page source. The source with the broken `span` tag looks like this:

[image: page source]

For Datepicker, I'm using

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery('#editable-post-name-full').each(function() {

jQuery(this).datepicker({

dateFormat: 'M-dd-yy',
showOn: "button",
                buttonImage: "../calendar.png",
                buttonImageOnly: true
           });

});
});
```

When I use `#new-post-slug` in the jQuery function, the DatePicker does not appear, I suppose because the div `#new-post-slug` is not in HTML until after the Edit button is clicked.

Does DatePicker need to be made to fire only after the Edit button is clicked?

All jQuery libraries are the latest for WordPress, which are jQuery UI 1.11.4, jQuery Datepicker 4.5.3, jQuerty 1.12.4. Site is on a private dev server; URL not available.

Comment: Have you checked if you have any additional styling done to the element? That would be my first guess but if that's not the case then please provide a Fiddle or something.

Comment: Can't see what the problem is. Unless you're able to provide more code, I can't reproduce any issue. You're also surprisingly unclear about how the `span` is broken. I think it is likely unrelated to the plugin described and jQuery. Moreover you've not described  what versions of what you're using. We have no idea what is going on in the background with what you're not telling us... all other assumptions included. The best bet for you would be to provide an actual URL to an actual page where this is broken, otherwise good luck.

Comment: I might add that you need to explain your motivations for why you want something to be the way it is as well. And your javascript code is missing the closing braces for the `each` i.e. `});`

Comment: You do realize that jQuery is now up to version 3.0.0 right? I understand if you want to avoid breaking changes, but 1.12.4 is a crazy old version.

Comment: Note that the HTML "After the Edit button is clicked" is invalid: `id #new-post-slug` is not a valid attribute; it should likely be `id="new-post-slug"`, and you have both a self-closing `input` and a close `input`: `/></input>`.

Comment: Thanks, site is on a private dev server; URL not available. I can't do a fiddle and include all the of the files. I added HTML that results from the edit button being clicked.

Comment: Thanks, Mike, I just saw that mistake. But the self-closing input and closing input tag are correct.

Comment: What do you mean correct? You can't use both. Don't use a closing input tag. Depending on your version of HTML, you don't need a self-closing tag either. Your `autocomplete` attribute has a spelling typo as well as the `type` attribute.

Comment: That HTML is generated by the CMS, not me.

Comment: Has your CMS been drinking? Okay, so your live update has corrected the above typos but you still have a self-closing tag with a closing tag for your `input` element. Be certain that this is implied, or just copy the HTML exactly without the keyboard.

Comment: Not much you can do, @BlueDogRanch, if your CMS is spitting out such horrific HTML. It's going to make doing anything with modern JavaScript almost impossible.

Comment: This sort of problem is **exactly** why a [mcve] is required for all debugging questions.  That is one that is both **complete** and **minimal**. Having such allows people who work on answers to duplicate the issue. Thus, they are able to actually see the problem and verify any fix. Generating a [mcve] also helps focus the question.  In addition, making the [mcve] often results in the OP being able to see, understand and solve their own problem.

Comment: Let me add that your edit button has no corresponding code to know what should happen on click...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answering my own question:**

This turned out to be simpler than I first thought, and hinged on what I thought might be the key: that Datepicker needs to be called after the containing div is visible. So I needed to use `.on()` to detect when `#new-post-slug` is visible in HTML. (This is where @bitifet was going with her answer, but I don't need to add elements or toggle elements; they are already in HTML). And, I'm trying to add the Datepicker to an `input`, and not a `span`, which I was wrong about to begin with.

This solution also places the Datepicker link and `calendar.png` next to the permalink field, and does not rely on a click in the `#new-post-slug` input to show it. That's helpful, as that gives the user a choice on whether to use Datepicker for the slug or use other text.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

jQuery(document).on('click',"button.edit-slug.button.button-small.hide-if-no-js", function(){

  jQuery("input#new-post-slug").datepicker({
        showOn: 'button',
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        buttonImage: '../path-to-image/calendar.png', 
        dateFormat: 'M-dd-yy',
  })
});

});
```

**Further notes:**

In order to use Datepicker with the Post editor, you also must load the script above (called `call-datepicker.js below`) in admin for Posts. *(This wasn't included in my original question as it was a needless complication).* This goes in your theme functions.php file:

```
//Add Date Picker to Posts Editor

function add_admin_scripts( $hook ) {

    global $post;

    if ( $hook == 'post-new.php' || $hook == 'post.php' ) {
        if ( 'post' === $post->post_type ) {     
            wp_enqueue_script(  'myscript', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/call-datepicker.js' );
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'add_admin_scripts', 10, 1 );
```

Remove the hook call to `post.php` and `global $post;` to enable Datepicker on Pages, too.

And, one further note for WordPress users. The WordPress theme I was using did not enqueue jQuery Datepicker in admin, so I needed to do that. This loads WordPress's own copy of Datepicker; and you may need to add your own CSS, too, from `datepicker.css` in your theme folder:

```
// Load Datepicker jQuery and CSS

function enqueue_datepicker_script() {

        wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-datepicker' );
        wp_register_style( 'datepicker_admin_css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/datepicker.css', false, '1.0.0' );
        wp_enqueue_style( 'datepicker_admin_css' );

}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_datepicker_script' );
```

Answer (score 1):

Please excuse this if it is not what you are looking for.  I think you want to be able to activate a date picker and use the results to set the *permalink*.  I think when you are talking about stuff breaking, it might be related to the date picker expecting an **input** rather than a **span** to host the control.

```js
function getLink(postDate, postName){
  var _dateString = postDate.replace(/\//g,"")
  var _template = "https://www.example.com/{date}/{name}/";
  var _link = _template.replace("{date}", _dateString).replace("{name}", postName);
  return _link;
}

var inputName = document.getElementById("postName");
inputName.value = "test-post";

var inputDate = document.getElementById("datepicker");
inputDate.value = (new Date()).toLocaleDateString();

var inputLink = document.getElementById("permalink");
inputLink.value = getLink(inputDate.value, inputName.value);

$(inputDate).on("change", function(){
  inputLink.value = getLink(inputDate.value, inputName.value);
});

$(inputName).on("change", function(){
  inputLink.value = getLink(inputDate.value, inputName.value);
});

$(inputDate).datepicker({
  showOn: "button",
  buttonImage: "https://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/datepicker/images/calendar.gif",
  buttonImageOnly: true,
  buttonText: "Select date"
});
```

```css
input { width: 100%; }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.css" />

<table style="width: 100%;">
  <tr>
    <td style="width: 100px;">Post Name:</td>
    <td><input id="postName" type="text" value="test-post"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Post Date:</td>
    <td><input id="datepicker" type="text" style="display:none;" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Permalink:</td>
    <td><input id="permalink" type="text" readonly="readonly" disabled="disabled" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, IRL took precedent over my question here on SO. I don't want to change the complete permalink, but only the editable part of the permalink, after the example.com/ But it does appear that I need to change the input rather than the span.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, changing ids of objects is a really bad idea (this perverts the meaning of the "identifier" word and is highly error prone).

Instead of that, I recommend you to simply add a class like "editable" to distinguish between editable and non editable objects.

That being said, the following code won't work as you expect (see comments I added for you):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    // Executed once on Document Ready event (Ok).
    jQuery('#editable-post-name-full').each(function() {
        // Executed over each (pointed by this) element whose id
        // is "editable-post-name-full" JUST NOW (not in the future).
        ...
    });
});
```

...so whenever you change that object id **AFTER** document ready event, below .each() callback over '#editable-post-name-full' selector was yet called without selecting anything.

If you want to change anything when some event is triggered, then you should rely on that event, not on classes or ids added by this event handlers.

And, if you want to undo that later, you need to manually undo on proper event or, alternatively, simply use two distinct layouts and show/hide them alternatively.

For example:

```
<span id="myDisplay" class="view">
   (Some date)
</span>
<span class="edit" style="display:none">
    <input class="datePicker" name="myDate" type="text">
</span>
<br />
<button id="myButton">Toggle Edit</button>
<script>
    $(function(){ // Not actually needed if code is at bottom of the document.
                    $(".datePicker").datepicker().on("change", function(){
                    $("#myDisplay").text($(this).val());
            });
            $("#myButton").on("click", function(){
                    $(".view,.edit").toggle();
            });
    });
```

( [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dths1fk1/2/) )

Comment: Thanks, IRL took precedent over my question here on SO. I can't change the HTML; it's outputted in the admin area of WordPress. Can I add this class to the current HTML?

Comment: Yes. You can thought .addClass() jQuery method.